# Glide : get cached file location in Android/Java

Tags: android, caching, android-glide

I am using the Glide to display images in my app. Now I want to know the location where the Glide is storing the cached images downloaded from the urls.

I am using below code to display image.

```
Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(mData.get(position).getImage())
            .centerCrop()
            .override(300, 300)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.default_small)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
            .into(holder.ivCapturedImage);
```

Comment: search android/data/{package name}/cache

Comment: I don't about that but it's based on how Glide set keys for caching, and please flag the comment so other people would know about it, or is it better to set it as an answer?

Answer (score 20):

This is one available method if you are using Glide 4.8.0 or higher

Kotlin:

```
val file: File = Glide.with(activity).asFile().load(url).submit().get()
val path: String = file.path
```

Java:

```
File file = Glide.with(activity).asFile().load(url).submit().get();
String path = file.getPath();
```

Then you can get a path looks like

```
/data/user/0/{package_name}/cache/image_manager_disk_cache/64c0af382f0a4b41c5dd210a3e945283d91c93b1938ee546f00b9ded701a7e40.0
```

Comment: Can you please answer in Java?

Comment: @PriyankaSingh Added Java version. Note that the try catch statement is excluded to make the code look concise.

Comment: @Joonsoo Can we load the file/image from this file path into an image view?

Comment: @MuhammadHanzilah Yes, with `Glide.with(context).load(File(path)).into(imageView)` we can load and use it for various purposes such as sharing the file.

Answer (score 3):

```
 private String getImgCachePath(String url) {
    FutureTarget<File> futureTarget = Glide.with(getBaseContext()).load(url).downloadOnly(100, 100);
    try {
        File file = futureTarget.get();
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        return path;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

the parameter url is network address of the picture，the 100,100 is the width and height of the cached picture ,you can change them according to your needs.
Then，The path is the cache path.

Comment: Nice catch! but i am already using above code (See the updated question)  to display image. So your answer would re-download the image again!

Comment: Nice! But this approach causes Glide to throw
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: YOu must call this method on a background thread`
Please how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
  Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                FutureTarget<File> futureTarget = Glide.with(context).load(vLink).downloadOnly(100,100);
                try {
                    File file = futureTarget.get();
                    String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    System.out.println("Path video  = "+path +"File  = "+file);
                    if (path != null) {
                        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(path);
                        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "shareMessage");
                        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
                        shareIntent.setType("video/*");
                        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image.."));
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Image Uri = " + path + "\nResource = " + resource);
                    }
                } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();
```